# How to determine a fresh login and a subsequent login in Community portal?

Tags: customer-community, loginflow, community-cloud, login-history

I have a login Flow setup for a Community. When Customer logs in I should show them two distinct screens based on the scenario first time login User and subsequent login User. I used Auth Session obj record to determine this. But the auth session record gets created as soon as Customer clicks on the activation link. So I would not know if he has really set his password and logged into the SF. Is there any way to determine this? Kindly help.

Comment: You can query [LoginHistory](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_loginhistory.htm) and/or Last Logged In field on User object

Comment: @identigral Last Password Change or Reset, Last Logged in are set to some value as soon as the User clicks on the activation link though the User has not explicitly set the password yet.

Comment: Login History shows type of login

Comment: @identigral LoginType is same before pwd set and after pwd set, just checked

Comment: Must be something with your setup. In our Dev Ed org, a brand new community with self-registration sends an email or text message with verification code. After a verification code is entered, Login History reflects a single login, as expected.